# OpenId development while disconnected from Internet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, openid

What solutions have people come up with to develop their web applications offline when they made the decision to use OpenId for site membership?

Couple of ideas:

1. Create two login pages one for OpenId and one for ASP.NET Membership
2. Create local OpenId provider with test accounts

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [an inversion of control container](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) to contain your OpenID implementation and for a quick implementation you [could use Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to provide preconfigured responses.

Answer (score 1):

Just mock it!

Answer (score 1):

I hardwire my login.aspx page to always do:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("http://blog.nerdbank.net/")
```

or something like that based on some variable.  That way, I don't actually log in using OpenId but it looks to the rest of the web site like I did.

Just be sure to either revert the change, or make it based on some condition that is only true in development. :)